# Sort of light beam effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm recreating an image for a customer, with better item symmetry and so on, I've almost finished it, although I have no idea about how to give this white beam effect on a layer on top of the main picture.

I drew some arrows pointing to those "white beams".

[image]

Comment: Hi Altrunox, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please show us what you have tried and why it didn't work? We are not a tutorial-on-demand website, we ask you to show some effort and we'd rather explain where your process is wrong than give a quick step-by-step. Please [edit] your question to include this information. If you want to know more about this site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help] they will get you up to speed!

Comment: Thanks Welz, I tried to use the pen tool, but the result wasn't consistent around the layer.

Answer (score 1):

You could draw a shape with the pen tool, fill it white, reduce the layer opacity, and apply an outer glow layer style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create this in 2 or even 3 layers. One as a shape with low opacity and Screen as blend mode (as mentioned above). Then, on a separate layer above that create a selection from the shape you initially drew, with the a generous feather radius. Fill the selection with white and set the blending mode to Linear Dodge (Add), then adjust the opacity until it resembles spreading light. Create a selection of the second layer and modify said selection (either expand or contract) and adjust the opacity again so it doesn't "wash out" too much.

I prefer this approach because it gives me more control over the amount of spread.